# ExifTool: Removing all metadata of an image except one in java application

Tags: java, image, imagemagick, metadata, exiftool

I want to remove all the metadata of an image except "Copyright".I am using exiftool of this .The command for this is "exiftool -all= -tagsFromFile @ -copyright Tunis_Bab_Souika_1899.jpg".But when I do this in java application .It somehow deletes all the tags.

here is the code snippet -

```
    val outputConsumer = ArrayListOutputConsumer()
    val exiftoolCmd = ExiftoolCmd()
    exiftoolCmd.setOutputConsumer(outputConsumer)
    val operation = ETOperation()
    println("File name" + sourceImage.toFile().absolutePath)
    operation.addImage(sourceImage.toFile().absolutePath)
    // exiftool -all= -tagsFromFile @ -copyright Tunis_Bab_Souika_1899.jpg
    operation.addRawArgs("-all=")
    operation.addRawArgs("-tagsFromFile @")
    operation.addRawArgs("-copyright")

    println("About to execute")
    try {exiftoolCmd.run(operation)
        println("Inside try")
    } catch (e: java.lang.Exception) {
        throw RuntimeException(e)
    }
    val output = outputConsumer.output
        .stream()
        .map { obj: String -> obj.trim { it <= ' ' } }
        .collect(toList())
    println("ooutput$output")
```

Comment: I don't know much about java or the way it passes data to the command line, but maybe split `-tagsFromFile @` into two separate `addRawArgs`?  Those are technically two separate arguments and it might be doing something like enclosing the whole thing in quotes when it gets passed. This would cause a failure in exiftool.

Comment: Use println(operation.getCmdArgs()) near 'Inside Try' to see what your parameters are that got added.
operation.addRawArgs("-tagsFromFile @") might need to be
operation.addRawArgs("-tagsFromFile", "@")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my question - This worked for me-

```
 operation.delTags("all")
            operation.tagsFromFile("@")
            operation.getTags("copyright")
            operation.addImage(sourceImage.toFile().absolutePath)
```